# Semantic Issue & Parse Issue: Missing context for method declaration & expected method body

Tags: iphone

Getting a Semantic Issue & Parse Issue: Missing context for method declaration & expected method body for pausing and resuming UIImageviewanimation methods. Declared these two method in the MainViewController.h file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

- (void)resumeLayer:(CALayer *)layer;
- (void)PauseLayer:(CALayer *)layer;

@interface MainViewController : UIViewController
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIToolbar *toolbar;
@property (strong)AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSTimer * timer;
```

methods in m file

```
-(void)pauseLayer:(CALayer*)layer
{
CFTimeInterval pausedTime = [layer convertTime:CACurrentMediaTime() fromLayer:nil];
layer.speed = 0.0;
layer.timeOffset = pausedTime;
}

-(void)resumeLayer:(CALayer*)layer
{
CFTimeInterval pausedTime = [layer timeOffset];
layer.speed = 1.0;
layer.timeOffset = 0.0;
layer.beginTime = 0.0;
CFTimeInterval timeSincePause = [layer convertTime:CACurrentMediaTime() fromLayer:nil] - pausedTime;
layer.beginTime = timeSincePause;
 }
```

I m confused what i have not defined here.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should place your method definitions within the @interface and @end block

```
@interface MainViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIToolbar *toolbar;
@property (strong)AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSTimer * timer;

- (void)resumeLayer:(CALayer *)layer;
- (void)PauseLayer:(CALayer *)layer;

@end
```